# What books are good to study Solid Mensuration?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Preferably I want those that contain the following topics:

Solid Figures

- Polyhedrons
- Prisms
- Pyramids
- Prismatoid
- Truncated Prisms
- Cylinders
- Cones
- Spheres

I've been able to find good references for Plane Geometry. But for solid geometry, it feels so limited. I cannot find a comprehensive reference that really deals with all kinds of 3D figures and is made in a modern way with detailed explanations, flow and illustrations.

Comment: Wow I misread this title.. Lol. What exactly are you looking for? This is fairly open ended as written.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I was going to suggest an OBGYN

Comment: I misread the title too XD

Comment: A book in Solid Mensuration or Geometry that deals comprehensively on 3D Figures and has the topics I have mentioned.

Comment: Are you looking for a K-12 treatment of these?

Comment: I don't really mind but I am also okay with a non K12 curriculum treatment.

Comment: Solid geometry used to be a standard course in high schools and colleges (up until roughly the 1940s), so there are hundreds of solid geometry texts freely available on the internet. See [this serach](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solid+geometry%22+archive.org), for example.